# 'Tag' does not contain a definition for 'FindTagById'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return something from my database.

When I call the method on the `Tag` entity, it says that there is no definition for the function I have created, but from what I can tell, I have defined the function.

**Compiler Error Message**:

> `CS0117: 'Tag' does not contain a definition for 'FindTagById'`

**ManageWorker.ascx.cs**:

```
var tagGuid = tagId?.TryParseAs<Guid>().GetValueOrDefault();

var tag = Tag.FindTagById(tagGuid);
```

**Tag.cs**:

```
public static Tag FindTagById(Guid? id)
{
    return Database.Find<Tag>(u => u.ID == id);
}
```

Comment: Where does Visual Studio take you when you hit F12 on `Tag` in `Tag.FindTagById`? Maybe you have another class? What does auto complete give you when you type `Tag.`?

Comment: A compiler error means that you *don't* call anything. The program won't run. Most likely you forgot to add a reference to the library where `Tag` is defined, or a `using` statement to include its namespace

Comment: Hitting F12 takes me to the FindTagById function as expected.

It's under the app namespace which is what i am using everywhere else in the same c# file.

in the head of ManageWorker.ascx.cs:
using App;
using App.Services;

Comment: Have you tried using the code from the `FindTagById` method in your `ManageWorker.ascx.cs` file - if so, does that work as you'd expect? I'm not judging your code, but if what I believe; that `Tag` is a simple object class; I would personally avoid any database calls from that method in the first place, and put them in your own Service or Helper that deals with database IO :)

Comment: I have tried that now. It works inline! but the `Tag` object is fairly in depth, it has a few methods on it such as validation before it gets sent off to the database. it also has a similar method called `FindByHirerAndName` which calls fine `Tag.FindByHirerAndName(this.Import.Company, tagName);`

Comment: OK, good to hear it's working fine :) I'm only trying to help out, so take what I say with a pinch of salt - but, I would look into separating your concerns out into a different (relevant) architecture. I don't know your code, so I can't comment; but I would advise having the object class itself being dumb - it only holds the properties necessary for it to be the object. From there I would have some methods on a helper/service (as I mentioned before) that performs your validation and/or database IO. Take a look into architecture and practices. Happy coding, and lastly, welcome to SO! :)

Comment: Thank you, you've been very helpful! I will look into the architecture a bit more like you said having a helper service will help a lot of the problems with this code base. Also if you suggest anything in particular that is good i'll give it a good look. Thanks again! :)